# 日本語に違和感: 投票ボタンのツールチップ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

> ↑ この質問は十分にリサーチされており、明確で、役に立つ
>   ↓ この質問は十分にリサーチされておらず、明確ではなく、役に立たない

- 「リサーチ」に違和感
- ↓ の文について、原文だと "or" だが "and" ぽい書き方になっている

> ↑ This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear
>   ↓ This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ↑ この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられる・実用的で分かりやすく書かれている
>   ↓ この質問には解決しようと努力した跡がみられない・実用的ではない・分かりにくい

Comment: +1 解りやすいと思います。researchを直訳すると「探求」とか「研究」ですが、entoさんの「解決しようと努力した跡」という意訳はSO本来の趣旨に近いと感じます。